# Validate a SearchResultCollection (active directory)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

im building a web application that has a login system but only for the administrator and its using Active Directory for the Credentials, I can retrieve its information with this code and it works, I get a "SearchResultcollection object" that has all user with corresponding password and username  and if the searchcollection isen't empty i would just add the username to a session variable.

Here's the code :

```
DirectoryEntry dir = new DirectoryEntry("ServerAdress", model.username + "@csnavigateurs.qc.ca", model.Password);
DirectorySearcher dirSearch = new DirectorySearcher(dir);
dirSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberof");
dirSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("userPrincipalName");
dirSearch.Filter = "(&(userPrincipalName=" + model.username + "@csnavigateurs.qc.ca))";

SearchResultCollection result;
 try
 {
     result = dirSearch.FindAll();
 }
 catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException)
 {
   ModelState.AddModelError("", "wrong username or password.");
    return View(model);
 }
 if () /*** Im trying to find the condition that goes here ***/
 {
    Session["utilisateur"] = model.username;
 }                 
   return RedirectToAction("AdminPage", "Admin");
```

but my problem is that I don't know how to check if this collection has 1 or more user, I tried to check in the object method and see if any method would work like a "list.any()" but I couldn't find one and im not sure if the object will be null if it dosen't find anyone with those credential or just empty, and I can't debug to check for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this `if(result != null && result.Count!=0)`

Comment: like i said SearchResultCollection dosen't have a .any() method

Comment: ok can you try this if(result!= null && result.Count!=0), I can see there is count method